# Packaging project with long description, warning about missing summary text in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-standard

Make a NuGet package which has a long `<Description>` value, issues the following warnings.

```
... \NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(204,5): warning : Issue found with package 'ClassLibrary1'.
... \NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(204,5): warning : Issue: Consider providing Summary text.
... \NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(204,5): warning : Description: The Description text is long but the Summary text is empty. This means the Description text will be truncated in the 'Manage NuGet Packages' dialog.
... \NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(204,5): warning : Solution: Provide a brief summary of the package in the Summary field.
```

But there is no `Summary` field on project property page...

[image]

How to set `Summary` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set Summary field?

To resolve those warnings, you can disable these warning by setting the `NoPackageAnalysis` property to true in the `.csproj` file:

```
<NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**However**, I want to share much more info about this issue. According to [.nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#general-form-and-schema):

> **description**   A long description of the package for UI display.
>
> **summary**   A short description of the package for UI display. If omitted, a truncated version of description is used.

Just as the description of summary "*If omitted, a truncated version of description is used*", so if we not set value for summary, a truncated version of description is used in the Visual Studio UI where the Description is too long it collapses it to fit the space:

[image]

To resolve this warning, we could add `<summary>Value</summary>` in the `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyModels</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Admin</authors>
    <owners>Admin</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <summary>Package description for summary</summary>
    <description>This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyModels.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyModels.xml" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then you pack this `.nupsec`, the short description `<summary>Package description for summary</summary>` of the package for UI display:

[image]

**But**

> summary is deprecated for NET Core projects and there are no plans
> of bringing it back currently.

That is why there is no Summary field on project property page. NuGet team will do to close [this bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4587) is going to remove this warning for netcore projects.

For tracking this issue, please check following link:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5688

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  ‎In short, to set Nuget display text exactly, have to use nuspec. If not needed, currently, have to ignore these warnings. I'm worried about using NoPackageAnalysis disabled, it would stops other warnings.